# Installation WordPress on IIS 7.5 - Internal Server Error

Tags: wordpress, iis-7.5

Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1. IIS with CGI. RewriteModule, PHP 7.4, MariaDB 10.4. Default page - index.php. phpinfo() works.

First page of wordpress is loaded. Second page - settings of database. Third:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in 
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php:1688
Stack trace:
#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wordpress\wp-admin\setup-config.php(310): wpdb->db_connect()
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1688
```

Comment: Share the WordPress version. `mysql_connect` was already removed in PHP 7.0 please check the documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Answer (score 0):

c:\Program Files\PHP\php74\php.ini:

```
extension_dir = "c:\Program Files\PHP\php74\ext"
extension=mysqli
```

Comment: Have you solved your problem? As of PHP 5.5 mysql_connect has been deprecated but it will still work (but give warnings), you can try to downgrade the PHP version to solve this problem.